# Azure Web Sites deployment with external Git that requires username/password

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have our own Git repos and we want Azure Web Sites to deploy from it.

For Azure Web Sites deployment with external Git repository. Looks like there is no settings to setup username/password/key to access the external Git repository.

Is it possible for the deployment to talk to an external Git that is protected by username/password/key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SSH key, you can follow [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#giving-the-private-key-to-the-kudu-service) instruction to establish the SSH key - then just pass ssh git clone url as external repo url.  For user and password, you can specify the repo clone url with embedded cred such as https://:@github.com/user/repo.git.  This is not recommended, however.  You have to give user and password which may be too powerful and, if compromised, can lead to security issue.

Comment: if I enter ssh git clone url azure tells me that the URL is not in a valid format.

Comment: same if I try username:password@github.com

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, not sure if it is the same though. I was trying to setup continuous integration from a private repo in Github that belonged to a organization I was only a collaborator for, not an owner.

Only a owner of the organization can do that, once he does you see "Windows Azure" as an "Approved" Third Party application for the Organization in the "Third-party access" section of the Org settings.